# how to process in debugging gdb trace

Tags: c++11, gdb

I am new to gdb. I found a below crash while running a process (written in c++) under gdb. I do not know from where I have to start understanding this backtrack to get the root cause. can any one help me with this?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555611560 in std::atomic<double>::load(std::memory_order) const ()
#1  0x000055555561130d in prometheus::Gauge::Change(double) ()
#2  0x0000555555611240 in prometheus::Gauge::Increment(double) ()
#3  0x0000555555611212 in prometheus::Gauge::Increment() ()
#4  0x00005555555f8356 in prometheus::Counter::Increment() ()
#5  0x000055555559dee6 in asnInitiatingRequest (pdu=0x7fffd800e4d0, sctpMap=0x5555557261a0, message=..., rmrMessageBuffer=..., streamId=0) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:2198
#6  0x000055555559eda8 in receiveDataFromSctp (events=0x7fffd8000e40, sctpMap=0x5555557261a0, numOfMessages=@0x7fffedd79fbc: 6, rmrMessageBuffer=..., ts=...) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:1509
#7  0x000055555559f698 in listener (params=0x7fffffff7460) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:972
#8  0x00007ffff7850de4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff7964609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#10 0x00007ffff7558133 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
(gdb) 




(gdb) f 5
#5  0x000055555559dee6 in asnInitiatingRequest (pdu=0x7fffe015ccf0, sctpMap=0x5555557261a0, message=..., rmrMessageBuffer=..., streamId=0) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:2198
2198    /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp: No such file or directory.



(gdb) p pdu
$1 = (E2AP_PDU_t *) 0x7fffe015ccf0
(gdb) p sctpMap
$2 = (Sctp_Map_t *) 0x5555557261a0
(gdb) p message
$3 = (ReportingMessages_t &) <error reading variable>  ---> what is this?
(gdb) p rmrMessageBuffer
$4 = (RmrMessagesBuffer_t &) @0x7fffee57b1b0: {ka_message = "{\"address\": \"127.0.0.1:38000\",\"fqdn\": \"e2t.com\",\"pod_name\": \"e2term\"}", '\000' <repeats 1978 times>, ka_message_len = 69, rmrCtx = 0x5555556fdd80, 
  sendMessage = 0x7fffe00014b0, rcvMessage = 0x7fffdc102a70}
(gdb) p streamId
$5 = 0
(gdb)
```

## code snippet

below is the code snippet and crash point given in the comment. which can help to get the crash reason.
please have a look.

```
typedef struct ReportingMessages {
    FormatedMessage_t message {};
    ConnectedCU_t *peerInfo = nullptr;
    long outLen = 0;
    unsigned char base64Data[RECEIVE_SCTP_BUFFER_SIZE * 2] {};
    char buffer[RECEIVE_SCTP_BUFFER_SIZE * 8] {};
} ReportingMessages_t;



/**
 *
 * @param pdu
 * @param message
 * @param rmrMessageBuffer
 */
void asnInitiatingRequest(E2AP_PDU_t *pdu,
                          Sctp_Map_t *sctpMap,
                          ReportingMessages_t &message,
                          RmrMessagesBuffer_t &rmrMessageBuffer, int streamId) {
    auto logLevel = mdclog_level_get();
    auto procedureCode = ((InitiatingMessage_t *) pdu->choice.initiatingMessage)->procedureCode;
    if (logLevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
        mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Initiating message %ld\n", procedureCode);
    }
    switch (procedureCode) {
        case ProcedureCode_id_E2setup: {
            if (logLevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Got E2setup");
            }

//            vector <string> RANfunctionsAdded_v;
//            vector <string> RANfunctionsModified_v;
//            RANfunctionsAdded_v.clear();
//            RANfunctionsModified_v.clear();
            if (collectSetupRequestData(pdu, sctpMap, message) != 0) {
                break;
            }
            struct sctp_status status;
            int stat_size = sizeof(status);
            getsockopt( message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_STATUS,(void *)&status, (socklen_t *)&stat_size );
            if (logLevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Start from SCTP %d fd", message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "SCTP status assoc id %d instrms %d outstrms %d", status.sstat_assoc_id,
                        status.sstat_instrms, status.sstat_outstrms);
            }
            if(status.sstat_outstrms == 1 || status.sstat_instrms == 1)
            {
                message.peerInfo->isSingleStream = true;
                message.peerInfo->singleStreamId = streamId;
                if (status.sstat_outstrms == 1 && status.sstat_instrms == 1){
                    if (logLevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
                        mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Single SCTP stream is used for sending from now on, assoc id %d streamId %d #instrms %d #outstrms %d, %s",status.sstat_assoc_id, streamId, status.sstat_instrms, status.sstat_outstrms, __FUNCTION__);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "Single SCTP stream used for sending messages even if there is a mismatch in number of in & out streams, assoc id %d instrms %d outstrms %d", status.sstat_assoc_id,
                            status.sstat_instrms, status.sstat_outstrms);
                }
            }

            buildPrometheusList(message.peerInfo, message.peerInfo->sctpParams->prometheusFamily);

...........
...........
...........

case ProcedureCode_id_ErrorIndication: {
            if (logLevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Got ErrorIndication %s", message.message.enodbName);
            }
#if !(defined(UNIT_TEST) || defined(MODULE_TEST))            
            message.peerInfo->counters[IN_INITI][MSG_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_ErrorIndication]->Increment();
            message.peerInfo->counters[IN_INITI][BYTES_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_ErrorIndication]->Increment((double)message.message.asnLength);    //crash at this point line no 2198

            // Update E2T instance level metrics
            message.peerInfo->sctpParams->e2tCounters[IN_INITI][MSG_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_ErrorIndication]->Increment();
            message.peerInfo->sctpParams->e2tCounters[IN_INITI][BYTES_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_ErrorIndication]->Increment((double)message.message.asnLength);
#endif
            if (sendRequestToXapp(message, RIC_ERROR_INDICATION, rmrMessageBuffer) != 0) {
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "RIC_ERROR_INDICATION failed to send to xAPP");
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: There is no canned procedure that starts from a stack trace (or any other mechanically generated information) and finishes at the root cause of the problem. You however may want to walk up the stack until you reach `asnInitiatingRequest` (which is is compiled in debug mode) and examine its local variables at the moment of the crash. Chances are that `Increment` is called with an invalid argument. You may also want to recompile Prometheus in debug mode to be able to look inside its functions.

Comment: when i want to frame 5 i get this error "no such file" plz see the main thread ...why so? how to resolve that?

Comment: Did you build it yourself?

Comment: no with a dockerfile. i just run docker build

Comment: well so this source location is on the docker. if you can find/mount the source directory you can instruct gdb to find source files at an alternative location https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

Comment: i have added prints to know the value of Increment() argument supplied. when there is no crash value of Increment argument is somewhere around 140736951766048  but at the time of crash its value is  293 (too small) do you think this can be a reason on crash?  and that argument is coming from function param   whose value is not be able to read  by gdb.   see main thread               $3 = (ReportingMessages_t &) <error reading variable>

Comment: It looks like the argument ought to be an address, in which case 140736951766048 is in the right ballpark and 293 is definitely not. "Error reading variable" might also mean that the address of the variable is incorrect, either because the stack is corrupt or because it's something that you get by dereferencing an invalid pointer. Perhaps try printing `&message` or whatever this variable is named.

Comment: i have added code snippet where crash happend. plz have a look in to main thread can we guess something with this?

Comment: I cannot do an interactive remote debug session. This is complex code and somebody who is not intimately familiar with it will have a hard time debugging it.

Comment: can we make use of "x" cmd in gdb somehow in this case? if yes any idea how? i am really new to gdb